# subtracting two integers bit by bit in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, bitwise-operators, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to subtract 2 integers bit-by-bit and was given this algorithm

```
b = 0
difference = 0
for i = 0 to (n-1)

    x = bit i of X
    y = bit i of Y
    bit i of difference = x xor y xor b
    b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)

end for loop
```

I have implemented up to this line `b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)`. How should I implement that last line of the algorithm in my code

This is what I have so far:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
prompt1 BYTE "Enter the first integer: ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt2 BYTE "Enter the second integer: ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt3 BYTE "The first integer entered is not valid ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt4 BYTE "The second integer entered is not valid ",0dh,0ah,0
X byte 0
Y byte 0
diff byte 0

.code
main PROC

L1:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    call readInt
    js printError1
    cmp eax, 0ffh
    jg  printError1
    mov X, al
    xor eax, eax

    L2:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    call readInt
    js printError2
    cmp eax, 0ffh
    jg  printError2
    mov Y, al
    xor eax, eax
    jmp calculation

printError1:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt3
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    jmp L1
printError2:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt4
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    jmp L2

calculation:
mov ebx, 0
mov diff, 0
mov ecx, 7

subtract:
    mov al, X
    and al, 1h
    mov dl, Y
    and dl, 1h
    xor al, dl
    xor al, bl
    mov diff, al




    rol X, 1
    rol Y, 1
    loop subtract
    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

The algorithm start from the calculation loop label. I needed to save the value stored in `al` register, in order to implement the last line of the algorithm, but since `dl` and `bl` is in used which general purpose register should I use to store value of `al`?

Comment: If you run out of registers then find which value can be a temporary value, then use the stack. push ax, use ax for temp stuff, then pop value back to ax kind of thing

Comment: yes, but push and pop instructions were supposed to be in later section, I'm not supposed to know those instructions in this lab

Comment: I only need to store value of al since that is really the only register that i want to modify

Comment: You can also store the value into a temporary variable. But you still have plenty of registers left, such as `AH`, `BH`, `DH`, `SI`, `DI`, `BP` (the latter 3 are 16 bit but can store your 8 bit value just fine). Furthermore you could do the calculations like `MOV AL, X; XOR AL, Y; AND AL, 1` saving you one register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your code is still wrong. Below is a piece of code that shows how to store registers in the stack. (It is however far from optimized)
In general if you’re out of registers, use the stack.
If registers are used in other places in your code and need to persist, use the stack to store them then reset them when you’re done.

```
calculation:
        mov ebx, 0
        mov ecx, 7
subtract:
        ; init
        mov eax, 0
        mov edx, 0

        ; al = bit i of x
        mov al, X
        and al, 1h

        ; dl = bit i of y
        mov dl, Y
        and dl, 1h

        ; save data for later (technique 1 the stack)
        push eax
        push edx

        ; bit i of difference = x xor y xor b
        xor al, dl
        xor al, bl
        or diff, al ; or instead of mov

        ; restore data (technique 1 the stack)
        pop edx
        pop eax

        ; b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)
        not al
        mov dh, al ; copy not al in dh (technique 2)
        and al, dl ; ((not x) and y)
        and dh, bl ; ((not x) and b)
        and dl, bl ; (y and b)
        or  al, dh ; ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b)
        or  al, dl ; ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)
        mov bl, al

        ror diff, 1
        ror X, 1
        ror Y, 1
        loop subtract
        ror diff, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
prompt1 BYTE "Enter the first integer: ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt2 BYTE "Enter the second integer: ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt3 BYTE "The first integer entered is not valid ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt4 BYTE "The second integer entered is not valid ",0dh,0ah,0
prompt5 BYTE "The result is: ",0dh,0ah,0
X byte 0
Y byte 0
sum byte 0

.code
main PROC

L1:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    call readInt
    js printError1
    cmp eax, 0ffh
    jg  printError1
    mov X, al
    xor eax, eax

    L2:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    call readInt
    js printError2
    cmp eax, 0ffh
    jg  printError2
    mov Y, al
    xor eax, eax
    jmp calculation

printError1:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt3
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    jmp L1
printError2:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt4
    call writeString
    xor edx, edx
    jmp L2

calculation:
mov ebx, 0
mov bh, 0
mov ecx, 8

subtract:
    mov al, X
    and al, 1h
    mov dl, Y
    and dl, 1h
    mov ah, al
    mov dh, al
    xor al, dl
    xor al, bl
    mov bh, al
    add sum, bh
    not ah
    and ah, dl
    not dh
    and dh, dl
    and dl, bl
    or ah, dh
    or ah, dl
    mov bl, ah

    ror X, 1
    ror Y, 1
    loop subtract

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, sum
    js printError1
    cmp ebx, 0ffh
    jg  printError1
    jmp printResult

    printResult:
        xor edx, edx
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
        call writeString
        call writeInt

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

ok I got it