# subtracting two 8 bits integer bit by bit in assembly x86

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, cpu-registers

so I'm trying to implement this algorithm to calculate the difference of two 8 bits integers

```
b = 0
difference = 0
for i = 0 to (n-1)

    x = bit i of X
    y = bit i of Y
    bit i of difference = x xor y xor b
    b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)

end for loop
```

this is what i did

```
calculation:
mov ebx, 0
mov diff, 0
mov ecx, 7

subtract:
    mov al, X
    and al, 1h ; find bit i of X
    mov dl, Y
    and dl, 1h ; find bit i of Y
    mov ah, al
    mov dh, al
    xor al, dl
    xor al, bl
    mov diff, al ; find bit i of the difference

    ; calculate b value for the next interation
    not ah
    and ah, dl
    not dh
    and dh, dl
    and dl, bl
    or ah, dh
    or ah, dl
    mov bl, ah

    ; rotate X and Y to get ready for the next iteration
    rol X, 1 
    rol Y, 1
    loop subtract
```

the problem with this code is its only work on the first iteration of the loop

so for example if I enter first number to be 2 and the second number to be 1

the when i go through the loop,first iteration, the x value would be 0 and the y value would be 1, the i bit of  the difference would be 1 and b value calculated would be 1
, but this only work for the first iteration, on the next iteration, I had x = 0, y = 0 and b = 1(from the last calculation), so I wanted my diff  to be 1 and my  b value for this iteration to be 1, instead I got 0 for both of them.

why doesn't the code work, as i was following the algorithm, and implement accordingly.

thank in advance

and

Comment: possible duplicate of [subtracting two integers bit by bit in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287263/subtracting-two-integers-bit-by-bit-in-assembly)

Comment: not really since this is 2 different issue, and why does my questions got -2 by the way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a higher level language first to understand the algorithm, then port that to asm.

```
#include <stdio.h>


//b = 0
//difference = 0
//for i = 0 to (n-1)
//
//    x = bit i of X
//    y = bit i of Y
//    bit i of difference = x xor y xor b
//    b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)
//
//end for loop


int main ( void )
{
    unsigned char X,Y,Z;

    unsigned char x,y,z,b,bnext;

    unsigned char i;

    X=0Xf5; Y=0Xf1;

    b=0;
    Z=0;
    for (i=1;i;i<<=1)
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        if(i&X) x=1;
        if(i&Y) y=1;
        z=((x^y)^b)&1;
        if(z) Z|=i;
        bnext = ((~x)&y) | ((~x)&b) | (y&b);
        b=bnext&1;
    }
    printf("0x%02X 0x%02X\n",Z,X-Y);




    return(0);


}
```

you might even re-write it a few times to approach real instructions.

```
   z=((x^y)^b)&1;
```

becomes

```
   z = x;
   z = z ^ y;
   z = z ^ b;
   z = z & 1;
```